# ListView+Viewpager Android

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, cardlayout

I am confused on implementing a design. I have a list of items which I want to show in a ListView. Now what I want to achieve is that the listview would show first 4 items and to view the next set of items, I want to enable view pager instead of vertical scrolling i.e the next set of 4 items should appear on the next page of the view pager.

Sorry, I just want to get a clear picture.
How can I achieve this? Thanks.

**EDIT***
Something like so if I have a list of 8 items.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look use a list view. Just show your first fours item as interviewees.
And  then the fifth item of list View will be View Pager. And pass all   the remaining data list after first four elements  to this view Pager Adapter which will show the rest of elements in horizontal scrolling of view Pager. But do not use List View and view pager in a same hierarchy.  This will cause you problem in scrolling and touch events. You can use different views for different items in List View. Better to switch to Recycler View instead of List View. Just have fifth element view a viewPager.
I hope this will solve your problem. Let me know  if you have any problem in achieving this.

**<*EDIT>**
Hey I did some workaround with ViewPager and RecyclerView as you said. Look at the screen Shots below. I hope you want to achieve as same. For Any issue drop a comment. I will try to help you out once I get time. You can find  the source code at https://github.com/MacSimmy/SpannableRecyclerViewExample which is my Github profile.
[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swdqi.png)[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What if I use a recyclerview showing first four items in cards on first page of view pager and go on using viewpager to show the next items in groups of 4. How can I do this? Can you please explain in a heirarchy?

Comment: Please see the picture I added

Comment: In that case use view pager and have a recycler view as a item view of  this  view pager. Just show four items in each page RV.

Comment: See  this is something you have to handle via some code logic.Just for e.g. , suppose you have dataList with 20 items in it. In viewpager adapter, getItemCount() method, return (dataList.size()%4==0)?dataList.size()/4?datList.size()/4 + 1; By this way you have 5 item Count for viewpager

Comment: And in  public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {}  method, just pass only required 4 items of  data list to RecyclerView Adapter.  Like if for position 1, pass first 4 elements of dat list  to rv adapter. Just like that from postion to postion+4 items of listdata to RV adapter. Hope you get thepoint

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96866/discussion-between-mahendra-chhimwal-and-hello-world).

Comment: Hey, Iam still struggling with this. Could you please post some reference I could use?

Comment: Hey .. Do you still in need for help?? I can do a quick work around in that case.

Comment: Yes . Can you please do that.. would be great help

Comment: Thank you for taking out time and helping. :) Ill try your solution out and come back to you

Comment: Hi, the solution you provided is working fine. But how can I get a click event on the cards? Right now when I click on the cards on first page, the items open fine, but as I go to next page and click cards there, the click events open as same as the previous cards i.e even If I click item 5, the item 1 is opened

Comment: Hey  hello world..I hope you have some real name :P.. Check my update in github. I commented the new changes in order to make it clear. I have made changes in RecyclerViewAdapter class only. And let me know if have any issue.

Answer (score 0):

i think recyclerview is best i have implement it before 
[image]

You need just rememner two things.

(1)vertical recyclerviews all row contant horixzontal recyclerview(visible/invisible).

(2) visible invisible mens if row have images put it in VISIBLE otherwise GONE.

Why not LISTVIEW:= becuse in listview with viewpager make gasture problem.
much more complex code to handle it.
thats why easy to Use **RECYCLERVIEW**